# Unable to deploy Shopify react app on ec2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, shopify

I have made a shopify POS app that is running good in development mode.
For dev mode, when i do npm run dev, it redirects to a url from where it takes configurations.

But how to deploy this app on ec2 instance?

For deployment, I did npm run build at project level, then inside web, I am doing npm run serve to start the node server.
But it gives "{"message":"**Missing Authentication Token**"}" all the time.

I even installed dotenv at web and imported it in web/index.js and put keys, host, etc at web/.env file. But still getting the same error.

Can someone please guild me what is the correct way to deploy this app?